Astro + React WebFramework won't deploy on netlify
I tried to deploy my site and when I rund build it doesn't show any errors in the terminal however
on Netlify it shows errors for each component I remove.
I tried to change path and components so far.
For example client:only="react" and client:only.
Also, instead of adding a components, I added the react file directly into the index.astro, but showed directly and error in the terminal after npm run  build

please share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
